# Win2012 - Background Application Whitespace CORRUPTION?

Tags: windows, whitespace

This is a really odd one: Could I ask any experienced Windows developers to please look at these screencaps, and advise if they've ever seen anything like this before: corrupted background whitespace, in Windows 2012: see these mages - these are seen within Win2012 VMs running on HyperV on Win2012 host:

[image: screencap 1 - showing whitepace corruption]

[image: screencap 2 - another view of whitespace corruption]

I should say - the machine works perfectly still: this is purely a visual effect, and appears to be a corruption of some sort of background (font??) - every new application pane opened, shows it - Windows Explorer does - but as soon as appn writes to the whitespace, it clears the corruption away.

This is an RDP view to the server but that seems unrelated: the actual RDP desktop background is not affected, just the whitespace in each Windows application pane. That's why I wonder if it's something to do with a font corruption or related.

Hoping to resolve it without a complete rebuild: is part of an industrial server application on a client site.

I should add  -  although the two pane examples I screencapped are within the Hyper-V manager, it's nothing specifically to do with that: all applications show it - Windows Explorer is similarly 'decorated'.

All wisdom will be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you already shutdown all the VMs and restarted the Host Hyper-V server? If not, I'd do that to start with just in case.

Comment: 1) I've seen this with RDP plenty.  Sometimes blank sections, sometimes the characters are there but garbled.  Usually disconnecting and reconnecting RDP will correct it.  Also, that search bar and shutdown button look 'non-standard' on the machine you're RDP'ing into. Does it have a 3rd party toolbar/taskbar utility installed?

Comment: Thanks for rapid replies gents.   AH:  you've given me hope...  I'd be pleased to find it's only at the RDP level.      This is a server shelved away in a rack room where I can't easily get a screen on it,  so for the moment I've had to stick with RDP:  I'd assumed it was an actual windows injury.     But - YES,  I have fully rebooted it,  host machine, two VMs and all,  and the problem came back afterward.   I guess I may have to go get a screen on it to be sure.    And no,  that's a standard toolbar I promise.   Win2012 out of the box.